# merge two data set by dplyr

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, dataset

I have data1 like:

```
id number
1   a
2   b
3   c
```

The other data2 like:

```
id  value
1   x
2   y
3   z
```

I hope to merge two datasets like

```
    a  x
    a  y
    a  z
    b  x
    b  y
    b  z
    c  x
    c  y
    c  z
```

The two dataset both have 10k of data, I really couldn't do it by hand, could some one give me some suggestion on this.Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps just the base R `expand.grid(data1$number, data2$value)`.

Comment: Thanks for you help!!! This is what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use 'expand.grid()' like lmo pointed out, or in a more tidyverse fashion:

```
library(tidyverse)
```

Creating dataframes ("tibbles"):

```
dt1 <- tribble(
  ~id, ~number,
    1,   "a",
    2,   "b",
    3,   "c" )

dt2 <- tribble(
  ~id,  ~value,
  1,   "x",
  2,   "y",
  3,   "z")
```

Using lmo's suggestion, expand.grid():

```
expand.grid(dt1$number, dt2$value)
```

A dplyr approach would be:

```
dt2 %>% 
  expand(id, value) %>%
  dplyr::left_join(dt1) %>% 
  select(-id)
```

Resulting in:

```
Joining, by = "id"
# A tibble: 9 × 2
  value number
  <chr>  <chr>
1     x      a
2     y      a
3     z      a
4     x      b
5     y      b
6     z      b
7     x      c
8     y      c
9     z      c
```